# How can I replace random 5 instances of a character in a string with another character in Python?

Tags: python, string, random

Let's say I have a string "GGTACGGATG" and I need to replace 5 randomly chosen characters with the letter 'M'. I'm not sure how to properly code this.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to make the most out of your visit here would be to provide some code of what you have tried already and share any of the error messages you are receiving. It will help in giving you more relevant help to understand where you were going wrong in your own attempt.

Comment: Start by choosing five random positions. You should have no trouble researching that.

Comment: Hint `import random`.

Comment: Another hint: google `python string manipulation tutorial`.  The one at pythonforbeginners.com looks like a great start.  If you try and get confusing results, post your code and the result of running it.  Learn to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Use `random.sample()` to choose five different indices, and replace those indices:

```
import random

my_str = "GGTACGGATG"

random_indices = random.sample(range(len(my_str)), k=5)
new_str = ''.join((char if idx not in random_indices else 'M') 
                  for idx, char in enumerate(my_str))
```